# convert ps to pdf

Tags: pdf, format-conversion

How do I convert *.ps file to a .pdf file? I tried several links given by google search, but either solution is really old and does not work for latest versions of ps and pdf files, or they do not make sense to me. Is there a simple utility to convert .ps file to .pdf file.

Comment: Question I was looking for, though my .ps is in landscape and I can't seem to find an answer to this question with the landscape option added. Any Idea's? (My .pdf ends up being some sort of portrait cropped version of the landscape .ps.)

Answer (score 65):

For a command-line solution: install the 'ghostscript' package:

```
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

and use the `ps2pdf` utility:

```
ps2pdf myfile.ps myfile.pdf
```

easy!

Comment: thorwing an error that current mode is local!!

Comment: could you paste the error text?

Comment: This answer helps me a lot. I have a pdf file with very bad embeded font. So I use pdf2ps to convert it into ps file, and use ps2pdf to convert to pdf file. The new font is much, much better now.

Answer (score 5):

Not on Ubuntu right now but try this.

If your post script file is called "test.ps"

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=test.pdf -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE test.ps
```

the non-self-explanatory flags are -dBATCH which avoids going into interactive mode and -dNOPAUSE which suppresses pausing after each page.

Answer (score 4):

Try to download and install GIMP once you are done open your.PS file with it and then go to save us and go to the drop down menu where you can choose the type of the file.. The pdf should be there, save it and it should work just fine.

Comment: there is no option to save as pdf :(

Comment: Hmm try to type manually as test.ps >> test.pdf sometimes it work.

Comment: File > Export and the set a filename ending in .pdf